# Update with aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having trouble changing an update from Oracle to SQL Server

I have doubt in an update in SQL Server. In Oracle, I managed to do it, but in SQL Server, I'm not getting it.

Below are the two examples (Oracle worked, however SQL Server returns the error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the list of sets of an UPDATE statement.

Oracle

```
UPDATE
  tab1
SET
  (t1.va, t1.vb) = (
    SELECT
      sum(
        CASE
          WHEN (t2.date2 - t2.date1) <= 30 THEN Coalesce((t2.x + t2.y), 0)
        END
      ) * 100,
      sum(
        CASE
          WHEN (t2.date2 - t2.date1) <= 60
          AND (t2.date2 - t2.date1) > 30 THEN Coalesce((t2.y + t2.z), 0)
        END
      ) * 100
    FROM
      tab2 t2
    WHERE
      t2.cd_xyz = tab1.cd_xyz
  );
```

SQL Server

```
UPDATE
  tab1 t1
SET
  t1.va = sum(
    CASE
      WHEN (t2.date2 - t2.date1) <= 30 THEN COALESCE((t2.x + t2.y), 0)
    END
  ) * 100,
  t1.vb = sum(
    CASE
      WHEN (t2.date2 - t2.date1) <= 60
      AND (t2.date2 - t2.date1) > 30 THEN COALESCE((t2.y + t2.z), 0)
    END
  ) * 100
FROM
  tab2 t2
  INNER JOIN tab1 t1 ON t2.cd_xyz = t1.cd_xyz;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the values you want to use in a sub-query then join then onto the table you are updating using the `UPDATE ... FROM` syntax from the documentation.

I'm not totally sure I've expressed your logic correctly given you didn't have any grouping, but did have a sum, but it should be enough to get you started.

```
UPDATE tab1 SET
    va = t2a.vaNew
    , vb = t2a.vbNew
FROM tab1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        cd_xyz
        , SUM(
          CASE
              WHEN (t2.date2 - t2.date1) <= 30 THEN COALESCE((t2.x + t2.y), 0)
          END
        ) * 100 as vaNew
        , SUM(
          CASE
              WHEN (t2.date2 - t2.date1) <= 60
              AND (t2.date2 - t2.date1) > 30 THEN COALESCE((t2.y + t2.z), 0)
          END
        ) * 100 AS vbNew
    FROM tab2 t2
    GROUP BY cd_xyz
) AS t2a ON t2a.cd_xyz = t1.cd_xyz;
```